# The CSV File Parse in Spark is not in correct format

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am New to Data Science, And I am using Spark with PySpark API. I want to Create a DataFrame of a .CSV File. And when i am doing that the Columns are moved to One Single Column as shown below.

The Commnds that i have used to Create a DataFrame of the CSV file are

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("MyFirstCSVLoad").getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.csv("order.csv")

df.Show()
```

[image: The CSV Data]

Can anyone help me how to fix that issue.

The Link to the CSV File
https://mega.nz/file/opQFxQbJ#Csjk-CtAkb1CwB6F3hULk3xJxkAOdPyAMMCFjI30MEk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I look at your data and its seems that your delimiter is ";" and not comma.
In that case when you read your CSV file you should specifici the delimiter.
Use:

```
spark.read.option("delimiter", ";").csv(fileName)
```